# If $f:\Omega\to L(U,V)$ is measurable, is $f(e_i)$ is also measurable?

Tags: random-variables, hilbert-spaces

Let $U,V$ be real separable Hilbert spaces, ($\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}$) be a probability space
$L(U,V)$ be the set of all bounded linear operator from $U$ to $V$ equipped with the norm
$$\Vert X \Vert_{L(U,V)}=\sup_{u\in U,\Vert u\Vert_U=1} \Vert X(u)\Vert_V$$
and $\{ e_j\}$ be an ONB for $U$.

Suppose that $f:\Omega\to L(U,V)$ is measurable. Is $f(e_i)$ is also measurable?

this similar type of measurability was used in the book
''Stochastic differential equation in infinite dimensions''
I cant really gasp how a fix unit vector makes  $f(e_i)$ measurable since it is $V$ valued,
measurability of $f$ as follows for any $A\in\mathcal{B}(L(U,V))$, $\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)
\in A\}\in \mathcal{F}.$
Any insight is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

The map $\Phi: L(U,V) \to V$ defined by $\Phi(T)=T(e_i)$ is  continuous,  hence Borel measurable . Compose this with $f$ to finish the proof.